# How do I add another email address for PayPal email Notification?

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I’d like to add a additional receiver email address for new orders to my Drupal Commerce site. I have added another PayPal receiver e-mail addresses to the the PayPal Express Checkout payment method using the Commerce PayPal module. (admin/commerce/config/payment-methods/manage/commerce_payment_paypal_ec). I am using the default Drupal rule for the PayPal Express Checkout module.

[image: PayPal Express Checkout settings]

[image: PayPal Express Checkout Rule]

However the PayPal email Notification is not send out to the secondary email address. I don’t see any errors in the Drupal Logs. Do I have to add another email address within my PayPal seller account? I really appreciate any help.

Comment: I believe you just need to modify the [Rule](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)

Comment: yes, that is what I've already tried. The PayPal email Notification is not send out the secondary email address.

Comment: you probably need to add a loop your rule, depends on how you set it up.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I've added a screenshot to my initial question. I am using the default Drupal rule for the PayPal Express Checkout module.